# TypeScript: No puedo usar funciones de array

Tags: javascript, typescript

no estoy pudiendo usar la propiedad length para la variable 'dataset'.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error:
Property 'length' does not exist on type '{ [index: number]: ChartDatasetI; total?: { [index: number]: TotalI; }; }'.ts(2339)

El formato de dataset es el siguiente:
dataset
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, total: Array(1)]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mas curioso es que no me da ningun error por iniciarlo como array:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

interfaces que conforman dataset:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En la interface chartDatasetI va a tener indices de tipo string variables y 2 indices string fijos como groupname y childs.

Comment: Estás declarando `dataset` como un objeto, no como un array. Mira la línea antes del error, tienes `let dataset : {....}`

Comment: Prueba hacer `let dataset : {... lo mismo que tienes acá... } []`. Basicamente agregarle `[]` al final.

Comment: no tampoco. El problema con eso es que si lo declaro como array como vos me explicas me da acceso al .length y demas pero no me permite acceder a las propiedades dentro de chartDatasetI.
El problema tiene que estar en otro lado, si se animan a crear una interfaz desde 0 buenisimo.

Comment: El problema si es ese. A las propiedades las accedes por índice. Por ejemplo: `dataset[0].propiedad` ¿O pensabas acceder directamente usando `dataset.propiedad`? No puede ser array y objeto al mismo tiempo.

Comment: ¿Y por que pones el signo de igual? Lee mi comentario bien. _Lo mas curioso es que no me da ningun error por iniciarlo como array:_  Pues yo veo la línea Roja.

Comment: En la declaración no me da ningun error.  Normalmente si lo declaras con un tipo invalido te avisa.

Comment: a ver.. lo "soluciona" ponerle array al final pero no se corresponde al tipo de datos que contiene. "Total" es aparte del array numerico. Lo que se me ocurre esta pasando es justamente que encuentra conflicto con la forma del objeto ya que tiene indices numericos y un indice del tipo string llamado "total".  Creo que simplemente no se puede , aunque javaScript lo permita y no de errores no encontre en typescript algo que respete el formato y no de error en .length
Actualmente ESTA FUNCIONANDO pero typescript lo toma como error.

Comment: A ver, es que basado en lo que muestra en la consola yo esperaría que tu declararas algo como `let dataset: {'COL11_SUM': number, COL13_SUM: number} [] & { total?: number};`. No se de donde tu sacas ese tipo de datos que le pones.

Comment: Bien, ahora edito y mando imagen de las 2 interfaces que lo conforman.

Comment: Prueba lo que ta acabo de poner.

Comment: Esta muy bueno eso que me comentaste con el "&" pero devuelta no me permite acceder a la propiedad "childs" ni "groupname". Error: Property 'childs' does not exist on type '{ [index: number]: ChartDatasetI; }'.ts(2339)

Comment: Bueno tienes que declararlas ¿no? Yo solo te puse las que se veían en la foto. Intenta completar lo que necesitas basándote en lo que te puse.

Comment: Creia que al colorcarle el tipo de interface a el array ya me deberia dejar acceder a childs siendo que esta propiedad la declare en la misma.  Vere que solución le encuentro.

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente se soluciono.
El problema principal es que es de "doble tipo". Siendo un objeto que contiene un array y una propiedad "total" que contiene otro array. Al ser así hay que indicarle con el operador "&" los 2 tipos que contiene para poder acceder a ellos.
La sintaxis quedo asi:

```
let dataset: ChartDatasetI[] & {total?:  TotalI[]} = [];
```

Asi "Dataset contendra un array iterable del tipo chartDatasetI y, a su vez,  podra tener una propiedad llamada 'total' que contendra un array del tipo TotalI."

De esta manera pude acceder a las funciones y a las propiedades sin errores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]